# What's the difference between CVImage and IplImage?

Tags: opencv, artoolkit

What's the difference between `CvImage` and `IplImage`?
I'm trying to integrate OpenCV with ARToolKit, but I'm getting an error here:

```
    CvImage *image;
```

The error is:

> expected '=',',',';','ask',or '__atrribute__'before *token

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CvImage is a deprecated wrapper to IplImage, don't use it. Best thing to use is cv::Mat, and if you need to interface with old code, IplImage.

If you really need to use it:
I assume you miss the legacy.hpp include. See the "legacy" module in current OpenCV.

Comment: uhm thanks @ypnos i trying to integrate opencv and artoolkit so i find this code, thats why I'm using CVimage.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong.

CvImage is used by cv_bridge to provide a Cv::Mat and the extra information of that is available in a sensor_msgs Image.

Take a look at the code in

```
http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/electric/api/cv_bridge/html/c++/cv__bridge_8h_source.html
```

and the tutorial:

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages
```

Comment: cv_bridge is not part of OpenCV, it is part of a ROS project. Also your first link is dead.